# C# Regarding Form Element Generation Performance

Tags: c#, performance

I am currently using syntax to generate my form elements, and all the content on start up. I was wondering if there is any performance gain from this? I just don't like the bloated feeling of using the editor in the source.

I mean, basicly if I were to use the editor I'd have this setup for my project: 3 panels x 44 icon images and text elements.
Where as in my code I can just use a loop to generate all the elements since theres not a whole lot of differences in the propertys except source or value.

Comment: Your question is very vague.  Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Are you asking about the designer vs code performance?

Comment: So for all intents and purposes, adding form elements in ( in SIMPLE WinForms ) staticly, versus through loops had no significant increase aside from the loop over head?

Comment: @TonyArnold: I'm not sure what you're asking with that last comment (might want to reread it to make sure it says what you want it to), but there's really not any legitimate circumstance to construct the form manually (rather than with the designer) for the purpose of increasing performance, regardless of the size of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no advantage to what you're doing. In fact, in a *small* way, what you're doing is *less* performant.

For example, consider you have ten text boxes on your form, each with the text "1" through "10" in them. Your form's designer code would look something like this:

```
textBox1 = new TextBox();
textBox1.Text = "1";
Controls.Add(textBox1);
textBox2 = new TextBox();
textBox2.Text = "2";
Controls.Add(textBox2);
textBox3 = new TextBox();
textBox3.Text = "3";
Controls.Add(textBox3);
textBox4 = new TextBox();
textBox4.Text = "4";
Controls.Add(textBox4);
textBox5 = new TextBox();
textBox5.Text = "5";
Controls.Add(textBox5);
textBox6 = new TextBox();
textBox6.Text = "6";
Controls.Add(textBox6);
textBox7 = new TextBox();
textBox7.Text = "7";
Controls.Add(textBox7);
textBox8 = new TextBox();
textBox8.Text = "8";
Controls.Add(textBox8);
textBox9 = new TextBox();
textBox9.Text = "9";
Controls.Add(textBox9);
textBox10 = new TextBox();
textBox10.Text = "10";
Controls.Add(textBox10);
```

(Actually, it would be broken up, since the instantiation, initialization, and addition are usually in different spots, but this is fine for illustration purposes).

Now, granted, this is verbose. But pure verbosity in generated code generally doesn't matter since nobody is writing (or, ideally, *reading*) it. Unless it hinders performance, of course, but I'm getting to that.

Using your approach, you'd (rightly) use a loop, since this code is quite repetitive and just begging to look a little more concise. Something like...

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    TextBox box = new TextBox();

    box.Text = i.ToString();

    Controls.Add(box);
}
```

Certainly much more readable. But, however, let's look at the work that the runtime actually has to do for each text box in each approach.

In the first, it does this:

- Instantiate a new `TextBox`
- Set the `Text` property to a string literal
- Add to the `Controls` collection

In the second, it has to do this:

- Increment an integer variable
- Compare to the terminal condition
- Instantiate a `TextBox`
- Convert an integer to a string
- Assign this intermediate string to the `Text` property
- Add to the `Controls` collection

Now, is the additional work substantial? No. Will you ever notice the ever-so-slight performance hit you take from the additional work? If you do, you need a new computer. But your question was whether or not your approach had better performance, and the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get mch out of this, you lose the design surface, not just for you but for your current or future colleagues.

I'd create user controls for the repeating ui, then you get the design surface, less stuff, and some encapsulation and potential reuse.